# Namespace cannot include methods error inside a C# console program

Tags: c#

I have this code that I wrote but I am getting an error saying that a namespace cannot include methods. Would appreciate any advice on what I am doing wrong and / or a suggestion on how I could code this in a better way to avoid this error.

```
namespace WriteToExcel
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<PhraseSource> data = ReadFromFile();
        }

        static List<PhraseSource ReadFromFile()
        {
            var filepath = @"/Users/psnet.data";
            return ReadFromJsonFile<List<PhraseSource>>(filepath);
        }

        static T ReadFromJsonFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
        {
            TextReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a `>`

The funny thing is, if you miss a really basic syntax component sometimes, you can get blasted with a bunch of errors that don't make sense. However, if you work through the errors you will usually find the right one

[image]

This

```
static List<PhraseSource ReadFromFile()
```

Should be

```
static List<PhraseSource> ReadFromFile()
```